# StackExchange.Redis - How to add items to a Redis Set

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to achieve the following scenarios:

1. Add 5 items of type `T` to a new Redis SET
2. Add 1 item of type `T` to an *existing* Redis SET

(i know SETADD doesn't care if the set is existing, but just listing my scenarios for reference)

I can see there is `SetAddAsync(RedisKey, RedisValue value)` and `SetAddAsync(RedisKey, RedisValue[] values)`, but i'm not sure how to work with it (and which overload to use?)

When i've used `StringSet`, i simply serialize `T` to a `byte[]`, then use that as the `RedisValue` param.

But not sure how to do it for sets.

This is what i have:

```
var items = values.Select(serializer.Serialize).ToArray();
await cache.SetAddAsync(key, items);
```

where `serializer` is a class which converts `T` to a `byte[]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is basically identical to how you would use `StringSet`. The only difference is that when setting a *string*, it only makes sense to set one value - but when adding to a *set*, you might want to add 1 *or more* elements at a time.

If you're adding one element, just use:

```
db.SetAdd[Async](key, serializedValue);
```

If you want to add a larger number of items to the set in one go, then first get the serialized items, for example:

```
var items = Array.ConvertAll(values, value => (RedisValue)serializer.Serialize(value));
```

or to tweak your existing code:

```
var items = values.Select(value => (RedisValue)serializer.Serialize(value)).ToArray();
```

The important difference here is that I expect your original code is ending up with a `byte[][]`, where-as you need a `RedisValue[]`. The `(RedisValue)` cast in the above should fix that for you.

Then call:

```
db.SetAdd[Async](key, serializedValues);
```

This corresponds to the [variadic form of SADD](http://redis.io/commands/sadd).